# Changing theme with system in children components

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, themes

I have a website using React with functioning dark theme changing and system detection, but am having trouble getting the Land and Nav component images to change on system change. They detect the system theme and successfully switch with the themeChange() function, but do not change when I change the theme in my system. Everything else does change on system theme change.

Home.jsx:

```
function Home() {
    const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState()
    const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

    useEffect(() => {
        if(prefersDarkScheme) {
            document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
            setDarkTheme(prefersDarkScheme)
        } else {
            document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
            setDarkTheme(prefersDarkScheme)
        }
    }, [])

    function themeChange() {
        if(prefersDarkScheme) {
            document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
            setDarkTheme(!darkTheme)
        } else {
            document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
            setDarkTheme(!darkTheme)
        }
    };

    return(
        <div className="Home fade" id="home">
            <Navbar themeChange={themeChange} darkTheme={darkTheme} />
            <Landing darkTheme={darkTheme} />
            <About />
            <Skills />
            <Projects />
            <Contact />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the Landing, same as the Navbar, logic:

```
function Landing(props) {
  const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
  const [darkNav, setDarkNav] = useState(props.darkTheme)
  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.darkTheme === true){
        setDarkNav(true)
    } else if (props.darkTheme === false) {
        setDarkNav(false)
    } else {
        setDarkNav(prefersDarkScheme)
    }
}, [props.darkTheme])

    return(
        <div className='Landing-Page'>
            <div className='Landing-box'>
                <div className='Landing-Text'>
                    <h1>Bridger Brown</h1>
                    <h2>Front-End Web Developer + Designer</h2>
                </div>
                <div className='landpages'>
                    {
                        !darkLand ?
                        <img src='./src/assets/wave-dark.jpg' className="fade" id='land-bg'/>
                        :
                        <img src='./src/assets/wave-light.jpg' className="fade" id='land-bg2'/>
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Skip the JS and just use HTML/CSS. For images follow [this](https://dev.to/dailydevtips1/light-and-dark-mode-image-in-html-lji)

Comment: The <source> image did not work, nothing displayed. Are you sure this is the way to go for React?

Comment: Okay I actually figured it out with CSS! You can set an images src by using 'content: url('...')', so if you add that as a custom var within your CSS prefers-color-schemes you can have it change dynamically.

Comment: Yeah that's another method, good job figuring it out on your own!